# Electron JS | How to change the icon of packaged .exe file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, icons

I have an electron application packaged via electron-packager.

==============
The platform is win32. For OS X (darwin) to change the icon of already packaged app you just need to replace the `.icns` file at the path `<approot>/Contents/Resources/name_here.icns` with another .icns file and that's done.

**But** the problem is with Windows .exe file. I have no idea how to change its .ico file. I need a method to somehow change the icon with node.js.
Any ideas?

Comment: You'll be able to change that and the publisher details with the program "Resource Hacker" which you can DL from here... http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 0):

Pass `--icon` arg to `electron-packager` or set it in config (if you are using it programmatically)

https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/master/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#icon

https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt (or `npx electron-packager --help`)

consider using `electron-forge`, `electron-packager` is quite low-level